# how to close_all_order from highest or lowest price on the bar?

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading, cryptocurrency

I have strategy like below and multiple entries per trade . I want to exit immediately after %x profit.

But close_all always take the bar CLOSE price not the desired highest or lowest price.

How can I do this. ?:

```
strategy(title =  - TAKE %x PROFIT", shorttitle="15 %1 strategy", overlay=true, pyramiding=10 , calc_on_order_fills=true, calc_on_every_tick=true , process_orders_on_close=true)

..
..

    
if (strategy.position_size > 0 )
    strategy.close_all(when=high>=longExitPrice)
    

if (strategy.position_size < 0 )
    strategy.close_all(when=low<=shortExitPrice)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    strategy.exit("Stop Loss/TP","LONG",  limit=longExitPrice)
```

strategy.exit is the solution.